# FindElement by Xpath is not working for "add New" button

Tags: java, button, selenium, xpath, click

```
<a class="add-new pull-right" href="javascript:void(0);">

    <span class="add-new-icon omedia-plus-circled"></span>

     Add New

</a>
```

The code is for "Add New" button which is present.

The xpath for the Add New button is :

```
/x:html/x:body/x:nav[2]/x:div/x:div[2]/x:div/x:a
```

I have tried this code:

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"javascript:void[0]\")]")).click();
```

but its not working.
Can you please help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"javascript:void(0)\")]")).click();
                                                             ^ ^
                                                             Notice the use of 
                                                             brackets
```

Comment: Really hard to see you just changed `[0]` into `(0)` ^^ You should use some strong font ** **

Comment: `** **` won't changed to strong in code-block, but notes added :)

Comment: wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"javascript:void(0)\")]")).click(); Will not throw any error but it doesnt seem to do the work

Answer (score 1):

Why not go with classname?

wd.findElement(By.className("add-new")).click();

A thing you should be aware of in general is that xpath expressions are considered the worst way to identify your elements than the use of CSS selectors, especially if you are testing in IE as the xpath implementation there is not native and is very slow. I suggest reading over http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors for a brief look at some examples and also maybe have aread of http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/selenium-xpath-marks-the-spot in order to see some of the negatives of using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate 2 buttons by this innertext. Try

```
//a[contains(@class, 'add-new') and contains(., 'Add New')]
```

for "Add New" button. And:

```
//a[contains(@class, 'add-new') and contains(., 'Add New Campaign')]
```

for "Add New Campaign" button.

Comment: From your help, tried the above but it seems to throw error.        Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@class, 'add-new')]"}
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds

Comment: Actually there are 2 steps: 1)Add new button click after this 2)Add Camp button click.. For Add Camp the HTML is as below <a class="add-new" href="javascript:void(0);">

    <span class="add-new-icon omedia-plus-circled"></span>

     Add New Campaign

</a> So is there a way to identify the buttons by the name" Add New Campaign" and "Add New..

Comment: You should separate 2 buttons by this innertext. Try 
`//a[contains(@class, 'add-new') and contains(., 'Add New')]`
for "Add New" button. And 
`//a[contains(@class, 'add-new') and contains(., 'Add New Campaign')]`
for "Add New Campaign" button

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@class, 'add-new') and contains(., 'Add New')]"}
Command duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:30'
 is the error coming when i try this